# Which derivation paths are used by the Abra wallet?

Tags: wallet-recovery, bip32-hd-wallets, mnemonic-seed

[Abra](https://www.abra.com/blog/2019-mit-bitcoin-expo/) have stated in [a reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/87cis7/need_help_sweeping_private_key_from_abra_wallet/dyiz4fz/) that their non-custodial HD wallet uses *custom derivation paths* to convert the user's BIP39 mnemonic seed into cryptocurrency address/key pairs. Has anyone figured out what these custom derivation paths are?

If Abra's nodes ever get shut down, users of the Abra wallet will need to know the derivation path[s] — otherwise their funds will be trapped, even if those funds are not being used as collateral in a contract.

In March 2018, the CEO of Abra said “[there is no standard structure for reconstituting p2sh based wallets across different apps via the seed](https://twitter.com/billbarhydt/status/975300261018140673)”, so I'm effectively asking if there's been any progress since then.

Comment: I think you are conflating things here? The custom derivation path for a noncustodial wallet in the first paragraph, and whatever progress you are looking for with respect to their Multisig (p2sh) (not entirely noncustodial) wallet, for which a derivation path would be insufficient? I don’t know or use Abra, but this is what it _looks_ like to me.

Comment: I took a look at Abra once, but the first thing it requires when generating a wallet is an email address. So I didn't go any farther than that...

Comment: @BrettDoffing Yes, I'm echoing previous conflation of two things. Abra Bitcoin addresses are said to use P2PKH, but when asked for more detail, their CEO replied by describing the situation with the multisig P2SH addresses that they use for their “synthetic asset” contracts. But in the Abra wallet, BTC and LTC are said to be real assets as opposed to synthetic assets. I agree that moving funds in a multisig address require multiple signatories.